# Como definir o tamanho de um botão em centímetros?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button

Preciso colocar um botão com altura e largura em centímetros, onde o tamanho se mantenha caso seja acessado em resoluções de tela diferentes. Isso é possível? Se sim, como?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É impossível fazer isto. Não existe uma forma de fazer porque não há como fazer confiavelmente.

Algumas pessoas usam uma forma calculando o DPI configurado, mas isto não reproduz a real relação do monitor.

O WPF tentou fazer isto mas os resultados são imprecisos e no fundo não cumpre o que promete.

[Nessa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4767664/221800) tem como fazer a conversão se quiser insistir, mas não fale que eu não avisei que não dá certo:

```
int CentimeterToPixel(double centimeter) {
    double pixel = -1;
    using var g = this.CreateGraphics())
    pixel = centimeter * g.DpiY / 2.54d;
    return (int)pixel;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WPF/EnableControls.cs).

Em geral isto nem é uma boa ideia. Cada pessoa tem uma necessidade diferente de visualização. O tamanho em centímetros pode ser bom para o papel, não para a tela.

Já usei sintaxe do C# 8.